# Flink cassandraOutputFormat tuple needs frozen value

Tags: java, cassandra, apache-flink

I have a flink project that will be inserting data in a cassandra table as a batch job. I already have a flink stream project where it is writing a pojo to the same cassandra table, but cassandraOutputFormat needs the data as a Tuple (hope that is changed to accept pojos like CassandraSink does at some point). So here is the pojo that I have that:

```
@Table(keyspace="mykeyspace", name="mytablename")
public class AlphaGroupingObject implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "jobId")
    private String jobId;
    @Column(name = "datalist")
    @Frozen("list<frozen<dataobj>")
    private List<CustomDataObj> dataobjs;
    @Column(name = "userid")
    private String userid;

    //Getters and Setters
}
```

And the dataset of tuple I am making from this pojo:

```
DataSet<Tuple3<String, List<CustomDataObj>, String>> outputDataSet = listOfAlphaGroupingObject.map(new AlphaGroupingObjectToTuple3Mapper());
```

And here is the line that triggers the output as well:

```
outputDataSet.output(new CassandraOutputFormat<>("INSERT INTO mykeyspace.mytablename (jobid, datalist, userid) VALUES (?,?,?);", clusterThatWasBuilt));
```

Now the issue that I have is when I try to run this, I get this error when it tries to output it to the cassandra table:

```
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.CodecNotFoundException: 
Codec not found for requested operation: [frozen<mykeyspace.dataobj> <-> flink.custom.data.CustomDataObj]
```

So I know when it was a pojo, I just had to add the @Frozen annotation to the field, but I don't know how to do that for a tuple. What is the best/proper way to fix this? Or am I doing something unnecessary because there is actually a way to send pojos through the cassandraOutputFormat I just haven't found?

Thanks for any and all help in advance!

**EDIT:**

Here is the code for the CustomDataObj class too:

```
@UDT(name="dataobj", keyspace = "mykeyspace")
public class CustomDataObj implements Serializable {


    @Field(name = "userid")
    private String userId;

    @Field(name = "groupid")
    private String groupId;

    @Field(name = "valuetext")
    private String valueText;

    @Field(name = "comments")
    private String comments;

    //Getters and setters
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Including the table schema in cassandra that the CustomDataObj is tied to and the mytablename schema.

```
CREATE TYPE mykeyspace.dataobj (
    userid text,
    groupid text,
    valuetext text,
    comments text
);

CREATE TABLE mykeyspace.mytablename (
    jobid text,
    datalist list<frozen<dataobj>>,
    userid text,
    PRIMARY KEY (jobid, userid)
);
```

Comment: Is it right `list<frozen<dataobj>` ?? there is a missing `>`

Comment: Yea, it still runs fine (which honestly is weird that it is fine with that missing). And I added the missing ">" just to be sure as well.

Comment: Add your table and type schema

Comment: Try to change `@Frozen("list<frozen<dataobj>")` to just `@Frozen`

Comment: Changed to just @Frozen, same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have found a better way than having to provide a tuple to the cassandraOutputFormat, but it technically still doesn't answer this question so I won't mark this as the answer. I ended up using cassandra's object mapper so I can just send the pojo to the table. Still need to validate that data got to the table successfully and that everything is working properly with the way it is implemented, but I felt this would help anyone who is facing a similar problem.

Here is the doc that outlines the solution: http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/2.1/manual/object_mapper/using/

Answer (score 0):

**Add `UDT` Annotation on `CustomDataObj` class**

```
@UDT(name = "dataobj")
public class CustomDataObj { 
    //...... 
}
```

---

**Edited**

Change `jobid` Annotation to `@Column(name = "jobid")` and `dataobjs` Frozen Annotation to `@Frozen`

```
@Table(keyspace="mykeyspace", name="mytablename")
public class AlphaGroupingObject implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "jobid")
    private String jobId;

    @Column(name = "datalist")
    @Frozen
    private List<CustomDataObj> dataobjs;
    @Column(name = "userid")
    private String userid;

    //Getters and Setters
}
```

Comment: Made changes you outlined in your first edit, still same error being thrown.

Comment: Check this http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.1/manual/custom_codecs/#creating-custom-codecs-for-user-defined-types-ud-ts

Comment: I see how it is suggesting a custom codec for a pojo that is annotated as a UDT, but my issue is how I can set a field of a tuple as frozen. The way you do it in a pojo is just by adding @Frozen, but for a tuple that can't be done.